# String replace file content with patterns

Tags: powershell

With PowerShell, I want to read a text file like

```
number,
number(2),
number(3),
number(12,4),
number(17,4),
```

Find all matches to `number(n,n)` in the file and replace it to `decimal(n,n)`. What is the easiest way to do this with PowerShell?

Answer (score 2):

if you want change the word *number* only where there is a decimal value *(xx,yy)* you can do it with:

```
Get-Content "old file.txt" | ForEach-Object {
  $_ -replace 'number(\(\d+,\d+\))','decimal$1'
} | Out-File "new file.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

One liner:

```
(gc .\input.txt) -replace "number(\(\d+,\d+\))", 'decimal$1' | Out-File output.txt
```

Comment: also the others answers are one liner ;)

Comment: Props for running the -replace on the entire contents and not looping, but you should have included _something_ about what you're doing, and try piping to `Set-Content` since it's faster.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician good to know.  I wasn't familiar with that one.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to replace the word `number` with `decimal`?

```
Get-Content "old file.txt" | ForEach-Object {
  $_ -replace "number","decimal"
} | Out-File "new file.txt"
```